# Can't get Admin access to my sites Facebook Comment Box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on my new site, and I wanted to intergrate the facebook comment box so people could leave authentic feedback.

I've got the box on the site, created my app , got my app ID and my facebook ID. Put them in the meta tags but it still won't let me delete peoples comments. I had a friend put a test comment on for me to try.

The page is  www dot bodmaster dot com/product/Bodology/EFX-10%20Oxygenator

I hovered the mouse over my facebook display pic to get my FB ID from the url...

[image]

This is how I got my app ID, and shows all my settings...

[image]

I've added the following meta tags to the page...

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="10150317838260636" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="414103721981616" />
```

Just to be thorough this is the fb script added to the page...

```
<!-- facebook script -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=414103721981616";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- end facebook script -->
```

and the code for the comment box...

```
<?php $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>" data-num-posts="10" data-width="470"></div>
```

Facebook did say, "it may take a few moments to update the servers"

It's not working after an hour, am I not waiting long enough?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated from you wizards.

Comment: Are you sure that `10150317838260636` is your profile id?

Comment: Gee... You've waited a **whole hour**???

Comment: Well that's how all the online guides to tell you to get it Lix. It does have FBID= in front of it, so you would expect that to mean facebook ID.

Comment: Ken, this is the first time I've really interfaced with facebook outside of the actual facebook site. Are their servers really slow ? That wouldn't surprise me. What time should I expect to wait. It's frustrating because I don't know if it's my code or just their slow server updates.

Comment: anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem here:

> I had a friend put a test comment on for me to try.  The page is www
>   dot bodmaster dot com/product/Bodology/EFX-10%20Oxygenator

**Change:**

```
<?php $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

**Reason:**

```
Your **site URL** is: http://www.bodmaster.com (set in your app settings)
Your comments URL is set to: http://bodmaster.com **or** https://bodmaster.com
```

Change the code as described above and...

```
Your comments URL is set to: http://bodmaster.com (even if SSL is currently in use)
```

Let me know if this works.